# Workbook contain macro save as new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, file, save

I have workbook contain macro. The report name is ppAug22.xlsm. Every month I will save new workbook - ppSep22.xlsm containing macro inside the new workbook. I put all the file path and new file name in sheet1 inside ppAug22.xlsm. After I run the macro in ppAug22.xlsm. It only help to save the new file ppSep22.xlsm. Other part macro cannot run. Could anyone have suggestion to solve it?
Regards,
Joe

Comment: You should create a copy of your current workbook and rename it, then update the data inside the new workbook. That way your macros will be copied over correctly and be available.

Comment: I can creat copy of current workbook and rename it. Afterwards, my macro include clear old data and input new data. This part of the macro inside the new copy does not work.